# Power Nap support

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, hardware-recommendation, power-nap

I read that [Power Nap](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html?siclientid=5899&sessguid=c27c554b-adbd-4e64-8fc9-c8a211867025&userguid=c27c554b-adbd-4e64-8fc9-c8a211867025&permguid=c27c554b-adbd-4e64-8fc9-c8a211867025#powernap) coming with Mac OS Mountain Lion will require a Mac notebooks with flash storage. Do they mean that by upgrading an early 2011 MacBook Pro to a Crucial M4 SSD would allow Power Nap to operate?

Any hints towards this new feature and whether it'll be available to all SSD users, or only the ones that purchased the new 2012 MacBook Pros is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. What they meant was that it runs on Macs with "built-in flash storage"<sup>1</sup>. That is to say, the MacBook Airs from 2010 to 2012 and the Retina MacBook Pro, i.e., the Macs with the (semi-) proprietary Flash hard drives and RAM soldered onto the logic board and Thunderbolt ports.

This means that it isn't supported by the 2012 non-retina MacBook Pros.

<sup>1</sup> Source: footnote 2 on your link, at the bottom of the page.

> Power Nap requires a Mac notebook with built-in flash storage. May require a firmware update.

<sub>**Edit**: As of the official release of 10.8, Apple changed the set of supported Macs for Power Nap to not include the</sub>
 <sup>late-2010 MacBook Airs. **Update**: as of 10.8.2, Power Nap is now supported on late-2010 MacBook Airs again.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really it. Apple does not specifically exclude third-party-reseller flash. Anyway, if this really should be the case, let's hope that some smart brains will come up with a hack to work around this artificial limitation.

Comment: @gentmatt It's not whether it's third-party or not that makes the distinction; it's whether the machines come with Apple's semi-proprietary Flash modules and have their RAM soldered onto the motherboard.